# C program : fibbonaci sequence

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main ( )
{
     long a=0,b=1,c,n=8;
     int i,j;
     printf("the fibonnaci series is:\n ");
     printf(" 0");
     for (i=1; i<n; i++)
     {
         c=a+b;
         a=b;
         b=c;
         printf ("\n  %ld",a);                                                                          
         for(j=2;j<a;j++)
         {
            if(a%j==0)
            break;
         }
         if(a==j)
           printf("- it is a prime number ");
    }
getch();
}
```

Output:

```
the fibonnaci series is:
  0
  1
  1
  2- it is a prime number
  3- it is a prime number
  5- it is a prime number
  8
  13- it is a prime number
```

I had a couple of questions regarding the above code. The ***if(a==j)*** statement lies outside the nested ***for(j=2;...)*** loop and ***j*** is not initialised outside ***for*** loop. so how is the ***if *** condition being tested? Secondly, can anyone please explain the function of ***break*** here. It would be reakky great if someone could explain the code to me in general. I tried doin it the followin way but it won't work :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
     long a=0,b=1,c,n=10;
     int i,j;
     printf("the fibonnaci series is:\n ");
     printf(" 0");
     for (i=1; i<n; i++)
     {
         c=a+b;
         a=b;
         b=c;
         printf ("\n  %ld",a);                                                                          
         for(j=2;j<a;j++){
            if(a%j!=0 && j==a){
              printf("it is a prime number");    
            }
        }


    }
getch();
}
```

output:

```
the fibonnaci series is:
  0
  1
  1
  2
  3
  5
  8
  13
  21
  34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The `if(a==j)` statement lies outside the nested `for(j=2;...)` loop and `j` is not initialised outside for loop....*

In the first posted code, `j` has block scope within `main()`. With `for(j=2;j<a;j++) { /*...*/ }` an initial value of 2 is assigned to `j`, and the value of `j` is incremented after the loop body is executed until while `j < a` (that is, until `j == a`). After the loop terminates, the value of `j` remains the same as it was when the loop was terminated, because `j` has block scope.

The situation would be different if `j` were defined in the loop. C99 added block scoping as an option for the declaration part of an iteration statement:

```
int main(void) {
    int a = 5;
    int j = 0;

    for (int j = 2; j < a; j++) {
        if (a % j == 0) break;
    }
    if (a == j) {
        printf("%d is prime\n", a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this case the `j` defined in the `for` statement *shadows* the `j` defined in `main()`, so after the loop exits the `j` used in the loop body is no longer accessible. Here `(a == j)` is outside of the block associated with the `for` statement, and `j` now refers to that defined with `int j = 0`.

> *Secondly, can anyone please explain the function of `break` here.*

A prime number is only divisible by itself and 1. Within the loop body, `j` is an integer that is at least 2, and less than `a`. If `(a % j) == 0` then `j` divides `a`, so `a` is not prime, and the loop is exited.

From a [comment under another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60862402/c-program-fibbonaci-sequence#comment107689685_60862541):

> *For `a`=5, the `for` loop will check for `j=2,3,4`. Since `a%j==0` is not true for `a`=5 it won't encounter `break` and end prematurely right? So `a`=5 and `b`=4 and since they aren't equal `printf` shouldn't execute.*

The loop iterates while `j < a`. So long as `(a % j) != 0`, the loop continues to the next iteration, incrementing the value of `j`. When `j == a`, the test `j < a` fails, and the loop is exited. After the loop, there are two reasons that the loop may have exited.

1) `break` was encountered when the test `(a % j) == 0` was satisfied; `j` is a divisor of `a` that is both less than `a` and greater than 1: this indicates that `a` is not prime.

2) The loop ran its course, terminating when the value of `j` reached `a`. The post-loop test `if (a == j) { /*...*/ }` tests for this condition. If `a == j` after the loop has finished executing, no divisors other than `a` itself were found for `a`, so `a` is prime.

Now we can appreciate the fundamental problem in the second posted code:

```
for (j = 2; j < a; j++) {
    if ((a % j != 0) && (j == a)) {
        printf("it is a prime number");
}
```

Here the expression `(a % j != 0) && (j == a)` can *never* be true, since `j` must always be less than `a` within the loop body. Whenever `j == a` at the top of the loop, the loop is exited. This is why the first code tested for `j == a` *after* the loop exited.

Answer (score 1):

> The if(a==j) statement lies outside the nested for(j=2;...) loop and j is not initialised outside for loop. so how is the *if * condition being tested?

"j" is declared outside of the first loop. Meaning its scope is the whole main function after that point. Thats why

```
for(j=2;j<a;j++)
 {
    if(a%j==0)
    break;
 }
```

will set "j" to two and run, until either "j" is not less(meaning: equal or greater) than "a" anymore OR "a" is divisible by "j" ("a % j == 0" means: There is no remainder after the division; the "break;" thereafter will exit the for-loop prematurely)

So ... after that loop:
"j" is either a factor of "a" OR its "a" itself.

```
 if(a==j)
   printf("- it is a prime number ");
```

And ONLY if a equals j ... THAN a is a prime number. Because otherwise a would be a factor of j and not a itself.

Comment: Hi, firstly thank you. From what i know, ***"break"*** exits u from a loop ryt? so it should exit the ***2nd for*** loop prematurely. But, ***if(a==j)*** is inside the ***1st "for"*** loop ryt. So even if the ***2nd "for" loop{for(j=2;j<a;j++)}*** encounters ***"break"***. the ***"printf" function*** after ***if(a==j)*** should execute everytime. But it doesn't why?

Answer (score 1):

Variable j is defined outside. So it declared but not initialized. When your internal loop initialize j, its value gets set and after loop its value will be the incremented one. 
As you know prime number is divisible by only 1 and number itself. Internal loop is checking that if number is divisible by any other number smaller than itself. If no number is found, j value after loop end becomes a. It will then check if a==j, so prime.

Now you can understand your second code and the error.

Enjoy Coding!

Comment: Thank you. But the thing is,  the internal *** for *** loop will keep checking if  ***a%j==0*** till ***j<a***; let's say for ***a=5***, the ***for*** loop will check for ***j=2,3,4***. since  ***a%j==0*** is not true for ***a=5*** it won't encounter ***break*** and end prematurely right? So ***a=5 and b=4*** and since they aren't equal ***printf*** shouldn't execute. Can u please explain how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main ( )
{
     // a, b, and c are the first terms of the fibonacci sequence
     long a = 0, b = 1, c, n = 8;
     int i,j;

     printf("the fibonnaci series is:\n ");

     // Prints the first term of the fibonnaci sequence
     printf(" 0");

     // This for loop reads numbers from i to n,
     // which is i = 1 upto n = 8


     for (i=1; i<n; i++)
     {

         /* This is the updating to the variables 
            for the next terms of the fibonnaci sequence */
         c=a+b;
         a=b;
         b=c;

         /* This is printing the current term 
            in the fibonnaci sequence which is a */
         printf ("\n  %ld",a);

         // This loops reads each of the numbers til a - 1
         for(j=2;j<a;j++)
         {
            /* Then, checking if a is divisible by j
               And if it is, break from the loop
               The modulo operator (%) gets the remainder of a divided by j */

            if(a%j==0) 
                break;
         }

         /* This is checking if a and j is equal.
            a and j will onle be equal if and only if the 
            for loop finished without entering 
            the if statement ---- > if(a % j == 0) which 
            signifies that a is a prime number
         */
         if(a==j)
           printf("- it is a prime number ");
    }
getch();
}
```

I hope this helps you understand that the statement `if (a == j)` is not part of the for loop but rather helps in checking if `(a % j == 0)` ever become `True`.

Comment: Thanks. But I had I more question. "break" is in the "for(j=2;j<a;j++)" loop right ?! So "break" should only prematurely end the 2nd nested for loop, However, "if(a==j)" is inside the 1st "for" loop so ''printf("- it is a prime number ");'' should be executed regardless of whether the the 2nd "for" loop encounters "break". How nis it working out?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. :D. Don't forget the 2nd nested loop will end in two ways, either 1. it entered the `if(a%j==0)` thus executing the `break`, or 2.  finishing the loop, which makes the value of `j` equal `a`. Sorry for the late reply. I think the explanation is better expressed by @ex-nihilo. :D